# JavaScript compare dates and set range

Tags: javascript

I have the following code what I'm trying to achieve is to compare current date with date in the table to change to different colours. Past date (red), Current+1day (green), Current+2 or more (red). Can anyone help me in achieving this? been stuck on it for a while.

```
var d = new Date();
var d2 = dayNames[d.getDay()];

var dayNames =[];
dayNames[0] =("Monday");
dayNames[1] =("Tuesday");
dayNames[2] =("Wednesday");
dayNames[3] =("Thursday");
dayNames[4] =("Friday");

document.write("<table id=myTable border=1>");
document.write("<tr><td>Week Commencing</td></tr>");

for (var i=0; i<dayNames.length; i++)
{
document.write("<tr><td>" +dayNames[i]+ "</td><td>");
}
if (d < d2)
{
document.write(dayNames.fontcolor("green"));
}
```

Comment: Where is your code to compare the days?

Comment: I don't even see any way in which the table cells are related to any date at all. Are you making a complete calendar or just a single-row table representing the current week?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the getDay() function:

```
new Date().getDay(); //returns day of the week as int from 0 to 6
```

Just to explain it:
`new Date()`without any parameter will create a Date object with current time, `getDay()` extract the day of the week from it